# Inequalities of summations lift to inequalities of summations of powers?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Let us assume:

- an at most countable set of indexes $I$;
- a set of reals $q_i$ with $i \in I$ such that $0\le q_i \le 1$ and $\sum_{i \in I} q_i \le 1$;
- a natural $n_i$ for each $i \in I$;
- a real $x \in (0,1)$;
- a natural $n$.

I conjecture that $\sum_{i \in I}q_i n_i \le \sum_{i \in I} q_i n$ implies $\sum_{i \in I}q_i x^{n_i} \ge \sum_{i \in I} q_i x^n$.

Is this true?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t believe me, but it seems that you are right. :-) For the sake of simplicity I assume that the set $I$ is finite.

The second derivative (with respect to $n$) of a function $f(n)=x^n$ is equal to $ x^n (\ln x)^2$, so the function $f$ is convex. Put $m=\sum_{i\in I} q_i n_i/\sum_{i\in I} q_i$. By Jensen inequality

$$\frac {\sum_{i\in I} q_if(n_i)} {\sum_{i\in I} q_i}\ge f\left(\frac {\sum_{i\in I} q_in_i} {\sum_{i\in I} q_i}\right)=f(m)\ge f(n).$$

The last inequality holds because $m\le n$ and $x\in (0;1)$.

For the infinite set $I$ we can try to take limits or use an infinite version of Jensen inequality.